# mixing rtl with ltr in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf, right-to-left, left-to-right

I'm using tcpdf to create pdf files in my webapp.

I'm using the writeHtml() function of tcpdf and trying to mix some hebrew with english,

when trying to combine both of the languages in the same line, the output comes out in the wrong direction.

for example - this is a piece of my code:

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF ( PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false );
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode ( "default", "OneColumn" );
    $pdf->setRTL ( false );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'freeserif', '', 10, '' );


    $html = '<body  style="text-align: center">';
    $html .= "<p> some words in english ואחכ כמה מילים בעברית </p>";
    $html .= "<p> כמה מילים כתובות בעברית and then some words in english</p>";
    $html .= '</body>';
    $pdf->AddPage ();

    $pdf->writeHTML ( $comments_table, true, false, true, false, 'R' );
    $pdf->Output ( $path, 'F' );
```

the expected output will be:

some words in english ואחכ כמה מילים בעברית

כמה מילים כתובות בעברית and then some words in english.

but the words in the second language in every language come in the oppsite order
my output is:

some words in english בעברית מילים כמה ואחכ

כמה מילים כתובות בעברית english in words some then and

as you can see - in the first line the english is ok - and the hebrew not, in the second line the hebrew is ok and the english isnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from tcpdf to mpdf which has a built in support for Bidirectional languages

Answer (score 2):

According to [this tutorial from w3.org about bidirectional text](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/):

> For inline text, **tightly wrap** all **opposite-direction phrases** in markup
>   that sets their base direction.

So your code should be something like this:

```
$html = '<body style="text-align: center">
            <span> some words in english<span>
            <span>ואחכ כמה מילים בעברית <br> כמה מילים כתובות בעברית<span>
            <span>and then some words in english</span>
        </body>';

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->writeHTML( $html, true, false, true, false, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

use setRTL():

```
...
$pdf->setRTL(true);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make output showing correctly with RTL or LTR write directions, simply you can check from your solution the current direction and store it in $direction variable, then check it if is RTL or not.
add this to your code :

```
$direction = $user->get_config("direction");
$style = "";

if ($direction == "rtl"){
        $style = "
                 <style> h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,div,p,table,thead,tr,td {
                         direction:rtl !important; text-align: right !important;}
                 </style>";
    }
```

Then Add this before you put anything in $html variable

```
$html = $style . "<HTML CODE>";
```

Finally Print your output :

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the Hebrew chunks in `span` tags with `dir="rtl"`. I know that would work in a browser, just not sure about `TCPDF`. You may also be able to include entire sentences that have mixed English and Hebrew within those `span` tags.