# tcpdf wrong font display

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

there is text like 'אַשְׁרֵי'

font 'Shofar'

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.../tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('test');
$pdf->SetTitle('test');
$pdf->SetSubject('testpdf');
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);


$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->setRTL(true);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$alef = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.../tcpdf/fonts/Alef-Regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$alefbold = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.../tcpdf/fonts/Alef-Bold.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$shofar = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.../tcpdf/fonts/shofar.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);

$pdf->SetFont($alef, '', 18, true);

$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
```

I connect font:

```
$shofar = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './shofar.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Output to pdf:

```
$html = '<font face="'.$shofar.'" style="text-align:justify;">אַשְׁרֵי</font>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdfname = rand().'_'.time();
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/books_pdf/'.$pdfname.'.pdf', 'F');
```

And in the generated pdf file, the characters of the letters fly away to the left, how to fix it?
in the

tag is the same.

[image]

On the site, for example, it is displayed correctly:

[image]

On site only:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'shofar';
  src: URL('/tcpdf/fonts/shofar.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

inside `<div> <span>`

Comment: no tcpdf expert, but I suspect RTL, your PDF code does not show it. maybe tcppdf manual has more reference, this is some Q&A on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559531/mixing-rtl-with-ltr-in-tcpdf (but I'm not certainly getting any clever by this, perhaps it helps you, YMMV)

Comment: thanks but I think it's not it, I have $pdf->setRTL(true);

Comment: Yes, that was not visible for me in your question, perhaps give it a bit more context. Btw. are you using the same HTML with those font-tags on the site where you show it works? If not, you could also show the HTML of that (e.g. below the second screenshot).